# Ansible variable with single quotes, space, commas

Tags: ansible

In an Ansible playbook, I have a variable that looks like this:

```
SSLPEER('CN=xxxxxxxxxx.nam.nsroot.net,OU=154607,O=MyCompany Inc.,L=Austin,ST=TX,C=US')
```

My code:

```yaml
- name: Format the CN and echo parameters
  set_fact:
    cn_formatted: "SSLPEER('{{ CN }}')"
    
- name: Set the SSLPEERMAP MQ Channel Authorization Record.
  shell: su mqm -c "echo 'set CHLAUTH({{ ChannelName }}) TYPE(SSLPEERMAP) USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER({{ usr }}) "{{ cn_formatted }}" action(replace)'|runmqsc {{QMName}}"
  args:
    chdir: /usr/bin/
    warn: false
  register: set_chl_auth_2_status
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Regardless of how I quote it, I cannot get the Ansible playbook to run correctly, please help.

I have tried both single and double quotes around the variable to run correctly, but having no luck!

Comment: Hi John Engineer welcome to SO. It is against the way ansible works to manually invoke `su`; that's what `become:` is for. It is also making your quoting story worse because you're trying to embed a shell command inside a shell command with a mixture of quotes. Finally, there's no need to `echo` when [`shell:` has `stdin:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-stdin) which will again help with your quoting story. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I was trying to describe; I changed some of the params in order to be able to run it locally, which you can also do in order to understand what's happening, but then uncomment the real values in order to run it for real

```yaml
  - name: Format the CN and echo parameters
    set_fact:
      cn_formatted: "SSLPEER('{{ CN }}')"
    vars:
      CN: 'CN=xxxxxxxxxx.nam.nsroot.net,OU=154607,O=MyCompany Inc.,L=Austin,ST=TX,C=US'
      
  - name: Set the SSLPEERMAP MQ Channel Authorization Record.
    #UNCOMMENT: become: true
    become: false
    become_user: mqm
    #UNCOMMENT: command: runmqsc {{QMName}}
    command: tee /tmp/runmqsc.{{QMName}}.log
    args:
      stdin: set CHLAUTH({{ ChannelName }}) TYPE(SSLPEERMAP) USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER({{ usr }}) {{ cn_formatted }} action(replace)
      chdir: /usr/bin
    register: set_chl_auth_2_status
    ignore_errors: yes
```

when I ran it locally, the `/tmp` file contained this, which is what the `runmqsc` will receive as its stdin:

```
set CHLAUTH(ch1234) TYPE(SSLPEERMAP) USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER(someusername) SSLPEER('CN=xxxxxxxxxx.nam.nsroot.net,OU=154607,O=MyCompany Inc.,L=Austin,ST=TX,C=US') action(replace)
```

Comment: mdaniel, Thank You so much for your assistance, I appreciate it.

John

Comment: Thanks for the reply!   It worked, but it wanted the password for the mqm user, which is a functional id, so the password is not known. To make this work, I wrote a script that's called by the Ansible script, with the proper formatting of the string in the script. It looks like this su mqm --command="echo 'set CHLAUTH($2) TYPE(SSLPEERMAP) USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER('\''$3'\'') SSLPEER('\''$4'\'') action(replace)'|runmqsc $5"